# CSS Border spanning across another div

Tags: html, css, border

The problem is that the border of **div#content** also appears in **div#navigation**?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WUI</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            div#header {
            }

            div#navigation {
                float: left;
                padding-right: 20pt;
            }

            div#content {
                border: 5px groove;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>WUI</h1>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Login</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <p>I like when you ride with that booty on me!</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** I want the left side (navigation) to appear as a sidebar to the left and the content after that (to the right). I'm applying the border to the content but that border also appears in **div** of **navigation**. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Can you please clarify what your question is? What is desired, what is in error?

Comment: also add please in which browsers this is happening

Comment: @Samuel Herzog: It will happen in all browsers, it's the nature of floats.

Comment: @Karpie I didn't test it, i just saw that the description was lacking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`navigation` is floating, which means it's taken out of the document flow, and the next element (`content`) moves up to take it's place.

However, `navigation` still has to float somewhere, so it's taking up space *inside* `content`.

To avoid this, either float `content` as well, or put a left margin on it equivalent to the width of `navigation`.

**edit:** after seeing your edit, I'd say the left margin idea would definitely be the better one.

Comment: both overflow:auto and margin-left does the job, but can anyone explain which one is better?

Comment: I don't understand why overflow: auto; works, but the advantage of it is you don't need a fixed width for your navigation. I don't know how browser support is though, since this is the first I've seen of it.

Comment: Overflow:auto is a solution for enclosing floats; it doesn't apply to this problem. It would apply if you had another div wrapping navigation and content, and navigation was longer than content - hence it would break out of your wrapper due to being floated.

Comment: Well that's interesting to know, but overflow: auto; seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: Huh.... right you are. Perhaps it's a side effect of enclosing inner floats; perhaps it kicks out intruding floats as well. However, much the same as I don't use overflow: auto for clearing floats (it gets buggy, I prefer a clearfix method), I wouldn't rely on it here.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm surprised I hadn't even heard about it until now. But if it's buggy, perhaps it's for the best.

Answer (score 4):

You need an `overflow: auto;` for your `div#content`. It's magical, hence no explanation will be given:

```
        div#content {
            border: 5px groove;
            overflow: auto;
        }
```

---

Well, after your edit, I can see your border isn't the problem. I usually do this:

```
html
{
  background-color: white;
}

body
{
  padding-left: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

#navigation
{
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

It makes you navigation static, and the content just magically works. The downside is that you have to use pixel-based layouts, which I don't really like doing. It's your choice.

Here's a semi-relevant thing I made a while back. See if it works for you: http://jsfiddle.net/dDZvR/12/

Comment: Your update does not seem to do what I assume you intend, for me. I didn't think left or top did anything with position: static; and it seems like that is true.

Answer (score 1):

you need to give float to the content because you give float to the navigation.
use this example:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        div#header {
        }

        div#navigation {
            float: left;
            padding-right: 20pt;
        }

        div#content {
            float: left;
            border: 5px groove;
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of how floats work. You're going to have to put a margin on `#content` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It can be corrected by adding a left margin to the div#content. The corrected code is here - http://jsfiddle.net/sparky/vctcN/

Answer (score 0):

you can add a

```
float: left;
```

in content and set the width yourself

Answer (score 0):

This one may works:

WUI

```
    <style type="text/css">
        div#header {
            display:block;
        }

        div#navigation {
            width:150px;
            float:left;
        }

        div#content {
            border: 5px groove;
            margin-left:160px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>WUI</h1>
    </div>


    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Login</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <p>I like when you ride with that booty on me!</p>
    </div>

</body>
```